# Passing arguments to Junit Runner with (Cucumber.class) from Junit Suite

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

We need to run a particular Junit Runner class with different tags one after the other . Ex : First @ATest test should run then @BTest test should run . 
So the only option we have is create multiple Junit Runner . I was thinking if there would be a way to pass this as an argument from Junit Suite ?

Comment: Maybe you could use [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) but I don't know whether the Cucumber runner supports Categories.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to define the sequence for features in @CucumberOptions.
This wont use the tags, but will run the features from the list in the order mentioned.

Comment: In our case we have the same feature with multiple tags . The tag is used to define the role of the User . So for a scenario which is common for multiple users its based on the tag they select the user and run.